# Which open-source C++ projects have good (inspiring) tests?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, open-source, tdd

What are inspiring examples of open-source software written in C++ with great tests?

I would like to read, study and follow.

Comment: I'm not sure if I know any open-source that can be marked 'tested'. So far from well-tested

Comment: @Yossarian - Some of the most robust, well-test and stable software is open-source.

Comment: Could you ask for examples of tests? as of now this question is not very useful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like mysql's exhaustive test suite, where they add a test for almost every bug they fix to prevent regressions.

Answer (score 0):

I have not read the source code, but PHP have a lot of tests which kan be easily run by `make test` after compilation.